# Google SQL Query with 3 criteria

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

The query below should give me a usage rate for the specified material code (B7 cell) with those matching criteria.

1. Should match the cell value
2. Should contain the 'Taking out of inventory'
3. Finally data should be between the date range of the last 4 weeks.

   `= QUERY(Inventory, "SELECT SUM(D) WHERE B = '"&B7&"' AND C = 'Taking out of inventory' AND A >= TODAY(-30) LABEL SUM(D) ''",-1)**`

The output should Sum up the values in the quantity column for the past 4 weeks. - Usage Rate 4 weeks

| Timestamp | Inventory # | Inventory Type | Quantity | Sales Order (S/O) # | Purchase Order (P/O) # |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6/20/22 10:42:16 | AAR | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 240 |  |  |
| 6/20/22 10:45:11 | AB1 | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 30 |  |  |
| 6/20/22 10:46:22 | ABC | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 3 |  |  |
| 6/20/22 10:47:52 | ABD | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 80 |  |  |
| 6/20/22 10:48:49 | ABN | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 21 |  |  |
| 6/20/22 10:50:14 | AAV | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 400 |  |  |
| 6/20/22 10:50:44 | ABA | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 3 |  |  |
| 6/20/22 11:02:00 | ABG | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 0 |  |  |
| 6/20/22 11:03:03 | AAX | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 85 |  |  |
| 6/20/22 11:05:35 | ABM | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 0 |  |  |
| 6/20/22 11:06:08 | AB5 | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 10 |  |  |
| 6/20/22 11:07:06 | AAS | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 60 |  |  |
| 6/20/22 11:07:48 | AAT | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 250 |  |  |
| 6/20/22 11:08:50 | ABQ | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 20 |  |  |
| 6/20/22 11:09:37 | AB4 | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 0 |  |  |
| 6/20/22 11:14:34 | AC3 | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 80 |  |  |
| 6/20/22 11:15:05 | ABW | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 80 |  |  |
| 6/20/22 11:18:29 | AAB | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 448 |  |  |
| 6/20/22 11:19:37 | ABY | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 0 |  |  |
| 6/20/22 11:30:35 | AC4 | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 10 |  |  |
| 6/20/22 11:31:54 | AC9 | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 22 |  |  |
| 6/20/22 11:32:30 | AC7 | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 80 |  |  |
| 6/20/22 11:37:17 | AC2 | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 1 |  |  |
| 6/20/22 11:40:40 | ABV | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 10 |  |  |
| 6/20/22 11:56:06 | AB2 | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 240 |  |  |
| 6/20/22 12:44:46 | ABP | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 50 |  |  |
| 6/20/22 12:45:28 | ABR | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 2 |  |  |
| 6/20/22 12:46:51 | AA3 | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 240 |  |  |
| 6/20/22 12:47:33 | AA4 | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 360 |  |  |
| 6/20/22 12:48:27 | AAE | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 50 |  |  |
| 6/20/22 12:49:37 | AAJ | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 100 |  |  |
| 6/20/22 12:50:06 | AA7 | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 880 |  |  |
| 6/20/22 12:50:58 | AA8 | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 485 |  |  |
| 6/20/22 12:52:04 | AAC | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 350 |  |  |
| 6/20/22 12:52:35 | AAC | Adding to Inventory | 20 |  |  |
| 6/20/22 12:53:17 | AAI | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 0 |  |  |
| 6/20/22 12:55:36 | AC1 | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 20 |  |  |
| 6/20/22 13:01:48 | ABI | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 8 |  |  |
| 6/20/22 13:02:14 | ABS | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 26 |  |  |
| 6/20/22 13:04:25 | ABF | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 50 |  |  |
| 6/20/22 13:05:52 | AB5 | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 58 |  |  |
| 6/20/22 13:06:34 | ABU | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 50 |  |  |
| 6/20/22 13:10:16 | ACD | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 86 |  |  |
| 6/20/22 13:29:55 | AAS | Taking out of Inventory | 15 |  |  |
| 6/20/22 13:30:46 | ABN | Adding to Inventory | 8 |  |  |
| 6/20/22 13:33:44 | AA7 | Taking out of Inventory | 60 |  |  |
| 6/20/22 13:42:13 | ACE | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 140 |  |  |
| 6/20/22 13:47:03 | ACK | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 170 |  |  |
| 6/20/22 14:01:51 | ADA | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 22 |  |  |
| 6/20/22 14:02:14 | AD7 | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 0 |  |  |
| 6/20/22 14:04:23 | ACM | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 85 |  |  |
| 6/20/22 14:10:52 | ACC | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 172 |  |  |
| 6/20/22 14:23:25 | AD4 | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 85 |  |  |
| 6/20/22 14:26:12 | AD5 | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 130 |  |  |
| 6/20/22 14:30:25 | AD3 | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 186 |  |  |
| 6/20/22 15:03:29 | AD9 | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 63 |  |  |
| 6/20/22 15:04:04 | ADO | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 9 |  |  |
| 6/20/22 15:06:03 | AD8 | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 113 |  |  |
| 6/20/22 15:28:35 | AAC | Taking out of Inventory | 50 |  |  |
| 6/21/22 7:51:51 | AAV | Taking out of Inventory | 18 |  |  |
| 6/21/22 11:13:09 | AB4 | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 100 |  |  |
| 6/21/22 11:13:45 | ABC | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 100 |  |  |
| 6/21/22 11:14:05 | ABG | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 50 |  |  |
| 6/21/22 11:14:39 | ABM | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 125 |  |  |
| 6/21/22 11:15:03 | AB5 | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 200 |  |  |
| 6/21/22 11:15:33 | ABN | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 100 |  |  |
| 6/21/22 11:15:50 | ABQ | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 350 |  |  |
| 6/21/22 11:16:15 | ABC | Taking out of Inventory | 17 |  |  |
| 6/21/22 11:16:35 | ABG | Taking out of Inventory | 11 |  |  |
| 6/21/22 11:41:12 | AB4 | Taking out of Inventory | 1 |  |  |
| 6/21/22 11:41:39 | AB5 | Taking out of Inventory | 1 |  |  |
| 6/21/22 11:42:11 | ABG | Taking out of Inventory | 3 |  |  |
| 6/21/22 12:32:50 | AAC | Taking out of Inventory | 2 |  |  |
| 6/21/22 15:45:04 | AAC | Taking out of Inventory | 20 |  |  |
| 6/22/22 8:51:11 | AD5 | Taking out of Inventory | 3 |  |  |
| 6/22/22 8:50:52 | AD4 | Taking out of Inventory | 3 |  |  |
| 6/22/22 13:19:04 | ABM | Taking out of Inventory | 125 |  |  |
| 6/23/22 10:57:06 | AB4 | Taking out of Inventory | 2 |  |  |
| 6/23/22 10:57:46 | ABC | Taking out of Inventory | 2 |  |  |
| 6/23/22 10:58:22 | AB2 | Taking out of Inventory | 1 |  |  |
| 6/23/22 10:59:17 | ABN | Taking out of Inventory | 4 |  |  |
| 6/23/22 10:59:52 | AB1 | Taking out of Inventory | 4 |  |  |
| 6/23/22 11:01:09 | ABQ | Taking out of Inventory | 350 |  |  |
| 6/24/22 8:38:06 | ABM | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 2 |  |  |
| 6/27/22 10:54:35 | AB5 | Taking out of Inventory | 175 |  |  |
| 6/27/22 10:55:12 | AAB | Taking out of Inventory | 7 |  |  |
| 6/27/22 12:08:11 | ABV | Taking out of Inventory | 1 |  |  |
| 6/27/22 13:35:29 | ADA | Taking out of Inventory | 2 |  |  |
| 6/27/22 13:36:09 | ABN | Taking out of Inventory | 10 |  |  |
| 6/27/22 13:38:27 | AD0 | Taking out of Inventory | 2 |  |  |
| 6/27/22 13:38:59 | ADA | Taking out of Inventory | 12 |  |  |
| 6/27/22 15:32:06 | AAS | Taking out of Inventory | 15 |  |  |
| 6/28/22 13:14:38 | AB4 | Taking out of Inventory | 50 |  |  |
| 6/29/22 7:54:13 | ABC | Taking out of Inventory | 2 |  |  |
| 6/29/22 7:54:42 | ABP | Taking out of Inventory | 2 |  |  |
| 6/29/22 7:55:40 | AAR | Taking out of Inventory | 4 |  |  |
| 6/29/22 7:57:40 | AAX | Taking out of Inventory | 2 |  |  |
| 6/29/22 7:58:21 | AA8 | Taking out of Inventory | 1 |  |  |
| 7/6/22 8:12:47 | AB1 | Taking out of Inventory | 12 |  |  |
| 7/6/22 8:13:32 | AB2 | Taking out of Inventory | 4 |  |  |
| 7/11/22 8:36:41 | AAV | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 320 |  |  |
| 7/11/22 8:37:42 | AAR | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 240 |  |  |
| 7/11/22 9:05:43 | AB2 | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 205 |  |  |
| 7/11/22 9:10:40 | AAC | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 270 |  |  |
| 7/11/22 9:14:01 | AA8 | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 445 |  |  |
| 7/11/22 9:15:01 | AA7 | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 880 |  |  |
| 7/11/22 9:15:56 | AA3 | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 240 |  |  |
| 7/11/22 9:19:40 | AA4 | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 350 |  |  |
| 7/11/22 9:20:37 | AAE | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 25 |  |  |
| 7/11/22 9:21:16 | AAJ | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 120 |  |  |
| 7/11/22 9:22:06 | ABR | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 2 |  |  |
| 7/11/22 9:24:20 | ABA | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 0 |  |  |
| 7/12/22 12:00:16 | ABF | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 50 |  |  |
| 7/12/22 12:01:55 | ABS | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 27 |  |  |
| 7/12/22 12:02:29 | ABI | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 8 |  |  |
| 7/12/22 12:08:24 | ABU | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 50 |  |  |
| 7/12/22 12:09:35 | ABT | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 36 |  |  |
| 7/12/22 12:11:37 | ABP | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 45 |  |  |
| 7/12/22 15:14:11 | AC5 | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 0 |  |  |
| 7/13/22 9:16:58 | ACK | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 160 |  |  |
| 7/13/22 9:23:02 | ACE | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 135 |  |  |
| 7/13/22 9:26:59 | ACD | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 85 |  |  |
| 7/13/22 11:47:05 | AD7 | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 0 |  |  |
| 7/13/22 11:47:44 | ADA | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 6 |  |  |
| 7/13/22 11:53:08 | ACM | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 90 |  |  |
| 7/13/22 11:57:48 | ACC | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 160 |  |  |
| 7/13/22 12:31:18 | AD4 | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 87 |  |  |
| 7/13/22 12:35:38 | AD5 | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 125 |  |  |
| 7/13/22 12:39:35 | AD3 | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 175 |  |  |
| 7/13/22 13:00:26 | AD9 | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 64 |  |  |
| 7/13/22 13:01:03 | AD0 | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 7 |  |  |
| 7/13/22 13:03:36 | AD8 | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 115 |  |  |
| 7/15/22 9:52:20 | AB4 | Adding to Inventory | 7 |  |  |
| 7/15/22 9:52:54 | ABG | Adding to Inventory | 7 |  |  |
| 7/15/22 9:53:22 | ABM | Adding to Inventory | 2 |  |  |
| 7/15/22 9:53:49 | ACK | Adding to Inventory | 8 |  |  |
| 7/18/22 6:07:57 | AAR | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 250 |  |  |
| 7/18/22 6:08:35 | AB1 | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 4 |  |  |
| 7/18/22 6:09:09 | ABC | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 1 |  |  |
| 7/18/22 6:09:43 | ABD | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 0 |  |  |
| 7/18/22 6:10:14 | ABN | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 0 |  |  |
| 7/18/22 6:10:47 | ABA | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 0 |  |  |
| 7/18/22 6:11:40 | ABG | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 7 |  |  |
| 7/18/22 6:12:08 | AAX | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 0 |  |  |
| 7/18/22 6:12:51 | ABM | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 2 |  |  |
| 7/18/22 6:13:43 | AB5 | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 25 |  |  |
| 7/18/22 6:14:25 | AAS | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 21 |  |  |
| 7/18/22 6:14:53 | AAT | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 240 |  |  |
| 7/18/22 6:15:26 | AB4 | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 60 |  |  |
| 7/18/22 6:16:01 | ABQ | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 20 |  |  |
| 7/18/22 6:20:58 | ABW | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 80 |  |  |
| 7/18/22 6:21:48 | AC5 | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 0 |  |  |
| 7/18/22 6:22:07 | AC4 | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 0 |  |  |
| 7/18/22 6:22:56 | ABV | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 1 |  |  |
| 7/18/22 6:24:30 | AC7 | Taking out of Inventory | 78 |  |  |
| 7/18/22 6:32:03 | AC9 | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 20 |  |  |
| 7/18/22 6:33:38 | AB2 | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 180 |  |  |
| 7/18/22 6:34:15 | ABR | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 2 |  |  |
| 7/18/22 6:34:51 | AA3 | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 240 |  |  |
| 7/18/22 6:36:08 | AA4 | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 300 |  |  |
| 7/18/22 6:36:32 | AAE | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 20 |  |  |
| 7/18/22 6:37:38 | AAJ | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 115 |  |  |
| 7/18/22 6:38:05 | AA7 | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 880 |  |  |
| 7/18/22 6:38:34 | AA8 | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 440 |  |  |
| 7/18/22 6:39:24 | AAC | Cycle Count (Full) (Physical count of quantities on hand) | 260 |  |  |

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: Kindly add input table and expected output table as [**text table**](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/)(NOT as IMAGE) to the question. Adding such [md tables](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer, as **it is easier to copy/paste**. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=QUERY(Inventory, 
 "SELECT SUM(D) 
  WHERE B = '"&B7&"' 
    AND C = 'Taking out of inventory' 
    AND A >= date '"&TEXT(TODAY()-30, "e-m-d")&"' 
  LABEL SUM(D)''", )
```

Comment: I added some of the rows from the 'Inventory' dataset to the original post. This is the dataset I'm running the query on. The Cell B7 in the formula is the Inventory# on another table that's checking against this dataset

Comment: I made some changes to the original formula.